# This coder requires that replaced objects be returned from initWithCoder

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am working on an iOS project which was building fine till yesterday. Today suddenly I am getting an error: `This coder requires that replaced objects be returned from initWithCoder`.

I tried searching the forums and they mention that the formatting of the `xib` has gone wrong. However, my project doesn't use a `xib` at all.

What could be the problem? This is how my main function looks

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions{


self.viewController = [[JASidePanelController alloc] init];
self.viewController.shouldDelegateAutorotateToVisiblePanel = NO;

UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
UIViewController *centerViewController = [storyboard instantiateInitialViewController];

self.viewController.leftPanel = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"HNLeftPanelViewController"];

self.viewController.centerPanel = centerViewController;


self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];


return YES;
}
```

I am posting the detailed output before for reference.

```
    2014-04-18 14:26:33.477 Nearby[1315:70b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: 'This coder requires that replaced objects be returned from initWithCoder:'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x03b935e4 __exceptionPreprocess + 180
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x037bf8b6 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x03b933bb +[NSException raise:format:] + 139
    3   UIKit                               0x029222ce UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 785
    4   UIKit                               0x02921fb1 -[UINibDecoder decodeObjectForKey:] + 114
    5   UIKit                               0x027cefc8 -[UIRuntimeConnection initWithCoder:] + 191
    6   UIKit                               0x0292227d UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 704
    7   UIKit                               0x0292247e UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 1217
    8   UIKit                               0x02921fb1 -[UINibDecoder decodeObjectForKey:] + 114
    9   UIKit                               0x027ce442 -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 1117
    10  UIKit                               0x02640605 -[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] + 280
    11  UIKit                               0x02640dad -[UIViewController loadView] + 302
    12  UIKit                               0x026410ae -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 78
    13  UIKit                               0x02666b15 -[UINavigationController _layoutViewController:] + 39
    14  UIKit                               0x0266702b -[UINavigationController _updateScrollViewFromViewController:toViewController:] + 235
    15  UIKit                               0x02667123 -[UINavigationController _startTransition:fromViewController:toViewController:] + 78
    16  UIKit                               0x0266809c -[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded:] + 645
    17  UIKit                               0x02668cb9 -[UINavigationController __viewWillLayoutSubviews] + 57
    18  UIKit                               0x027a2181 -[UILayoutContainerView layoutSubviews] + 213
    19  UIKit                               0x02598267 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 355
    20  libobjc.A.dylib                     0x037d181f -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:] + 70
    21  QuartzCore                          0x017052ea -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 148
    22  QuartzCore                          0x016f90d4 _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 380
    23  QuartzCore                          0x01705235 -[CALayer layoutIfNeeded] + 160
    24  UIKit                               0x02653613 -[UIViewController window:setupWithInterfaceOrientation:] + 304
    25  UIKit                               0x02572177 -[UIWindow _setRotatableClient:toOrientation:updateStatusBar:duration:force:isRotating:] + 5212
    26  UIKit                               0x02570d16 -[UIWindow _setRotatableClient:toOrientation:updateStatusBar:duration:force:] + 82
    27  UIKit                               0x02570be8 -[UIWindow _setRotatableViewOrientation:updateStatusBar:duration:force:] + 117
    28  UIKit                               0x02570c70 -[UIWindow _setRotatableViewOrientation:duration:force:] + 67
    29  UIKit                               0x0256fd0a __57-[UIWindow _updateToInterfaceOrientation:duration:force:]_block_invoke + 120
    30  UIKit                               0x0256fc6c -[UIWindow _updateToInterfaceOrientation:duration:force:] + 400
    31  UIKit                               0x025709c3 -[UIWindow setAutorotates:forceUpdateInterfaceOrientation:] + 870
    32  UIKit                               0x02573fb6 -[UIWindow setDelegate:] + 449
    33  UIKit                               0x02645737 -[UIViewController _tryBecomeRootViewControllerInWindow:] + 180
    34  UIKit                               0x02569c1c -[UIWindow addRootViewControllerViewIfPossible] + 609
    35  UIKit                               0x02569d97 -[UIWindow _setHidden:forced:] + 312
    36  UIKit                               0x0256a02d -[UIWindow _orderFrontWithoutMakingKey] + 49
    37  UIKit                               0x0257489a -[UIWindow makeKeyAndVisible] + 65
    38  Nearby                              0x000421b2 -[HNAppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] + 754
    39  UIKit                               0x02527355 -[UIApplication _handleDelegateCallbacksWithOptions:isSuspended:restoreState:] + 309
    40  UIKit                               0x02527b95 -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForURL:payload:suspended:] + 1536
    41  UIKit                               0x0252c3a8 -[UIApplication _runWithURL:payload:launchOrientation:statusBarStyle:statusBarHidden:] + 824
    42  UIKit                               0x0254087c -[UIApplication handleEvent:withNewEvent:] + 3447
    43  UIKit                               0x02540de9 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 85
    44  UIKit                               0x0252e025 _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 736
    45  GraphicsServices                    0x04f652f6 _PurpleEventCallback + 776
    46  GraphicsServices                    0x04f64e01 PurpleEventCallback + 46
    47  CoreFoundation                      0x03b0ed65 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 53
    48  CoreFoundation                      0x03b0ea9b __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 523
    49  CoreFoundation                      0x03b3977c __CFRunLoopRun + 2156
    50  CoreFoundation                      0x03b38ac3 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467
    51  CoreFoundation                      0x03b388db CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
    52  UIKit                               0x0252badd -[UIApplication _run] + 840
    53  UIKit                               0x0252dd3b UIApplicationMain + 1225
    54  Nearby                              0x0004b72d main + 141
    55  libdyld.dylib                       0x04104701 start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Comment: Did you call `[UIViewController alloc] initWithNib...` ?

Comment: I haven't called initWithNib anywhere. But when I created ViewControllers, they have this default function.

Comment: - (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

Comment: I have added some code of relevance to my original post above. Please suggest what could be the issue. Thanks

Comment: You're using storyboard... Remove all the code in `- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions` except `return YES;`

Comment: I tried this and it doesn't work either. Btw, the reason for additional code in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions was that I was using side pannel. Anyway, I don't care about the side panel for now.. need to get views working.

Comment: Would be great if you could let me know KudoCC

Comment: You shouldn't call the method `self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];` when using storyboard I think.

Comment: @user3548288 "my project doesn't use a xib at all" ... `UIStoryboard *storyboard = `: you need to research what nib (xib, storyboard) files are. And yes, something is wrong at your storyboard.

Comment: Open your `Main.storyboard` and see if it gives any errors opening (malformed XML?) or opens correctly and then Xcode shows code warnings/errors (misconfiguration).

Comment: You have probably connected an outlet to a property that doesn't conform to <NSCoding>